# Save variables to a file

Tags: ruby, methods, save

I'm working on a Ruby project on RHEL6 at work which includes a quiz. The answers are bool variables that change if your answer is correct or not.

Atm I'm trying to add a save option for the bools, but I'm encountering a problem. How can I access the variables written in the code from a method?

code sample:

```
@inf_cmd_q1 = true
@inf_cmd_q2 = false
@inf_cmd_q3 = true
@inf_cmd_q4 = false
@inf_cmd_q5 = true
@inf_cmd_q6 = true
@inf_cmd_q7 = false
@inf_cmd_q8 = true
@inf_cmd_q9 = true
@inf_cmd_q10 = false

def save(fname)
    for i 1..10
        system("echo #{@inf_cmd_q#{i}} >> /quiz/#{fname}")
    end
end
```

- inf_cmd_q(num)- answer's bool var
- fname- name of the file to save to

I know it won't work, but I'm having hard time figuring how to make it work, plus I never worked with instance variables, because I just started using Ruby.

any advices?

Comment: Why don't you use an array, instead of 10 different digit-based variables?

Comment: @SimoneCarletti or hash

Comment: I tried using hash, but it didn't look that well in the code (which is around 400 lines now).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can print `instance variables` dynamicly.

```
  1.upto 10 do |i|
    puts "#{self.instance_variable_get("@inf_cmd_q#{i}")}"
  end
```

If you need to save data to File, use `File` methods.
BTW: for saving data you can use `JSON` data structure.